# bottom right page numbering in table of content, list of figures, table and nomenclature

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, nomenclature

I wanted to have all page numbering at right bottom of each page. So I used package `fancyhdr`.

I put this at the preamble

```
%customize page numbering on right hand side
\fancyhf{} %clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

It works OK, especially at first page of every chapters with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` where I put after `\chapter{}`.

but it doesn't work at these pages below, table of contents, figures, tables and nomenclature. They are appear bottom of page at the middle. Am I missing something here?

```
%Table of content

\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}

%List of tables 

\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}

%List of figures

\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}

%Nomenclature

\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{NOMENCLATURE}
\printnomenclature[3cm]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: thanks Peter Grill for the reminder.... mine document class is report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard document classes, the first page of a chapter is set using `\thispagestyle{plain}`. You can redefine the `plain` page style to be similar to your `fancy` page style, which will make all references to `\thispagestyle{plain}` be equivalent to `\thispagestyle{fancy}` by following the guideline in the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) (section **7 Redeﬁning `plain` style**, p 7):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
%customize page numbering on right hand side
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefining plain page style
  \fancyhf{} %clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
}%
\fancyhf{} %clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}% Fancy page style
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Second chapter}%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[21-40]
\chapter{Last chapter}%\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
```

By redefining the `plain` page style, you don't have to issue `\thispagestyle{fancy}` at the start of every chapter, as is indicated in the above MWE.

Comment: sorry.. may i ask one more question. i want to have 8pt size, currently is 12pt as the whole document in 12pt. i tried to insert `\fancyfoot[RO]{\fontsize{8pt}\thepage}`, it doesn't work. thank you for your advice.